# Get filename from URL using Regular Expressions or Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url, filenames

I need to get the filename from the URL address.

Here is the criteria:

It need to return empty string `""` in following scenarios:

```
http://somedomain.com
http://www.somedomain.com
http://somedomain.com/
http://www.somedomain.com/
```

And return filename.php in the following scenarios:

```
http://somedomain.com/filename.php?query
http://www.somedomain.com/filename.php?query
http://somedomain.com/filename.php#query
http://www.somedomain.com/filename.php#query
```

I found this regular expression

`[\w_.-]*?(?=[\?\#])|[\w_.-]*$` from [here](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/url_regex.htm)

however it returns `somedomain.com` on input `http://somedomain.com`. I can't figure out how to modify it to ignore the domain when there is no `/` at the end of it.

If it is difficult to do with regular expressions, I will appreciate a JavaScript solution as well.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you are writing script in a browser, there is already a full-featured URL parser for you to take advantage of, without having to write unreliable incomplete regexen. Use an HTMLAnchorElement to read the `location`-like properties `host`, `pathname`, `search`, `hash` etc.:

```
var a= document.createElement('a');
a.href= 'http://somedomain.com/dirname/filename.php?query';
var filename= a.pathname.split('/').pop(); // filename.php
```

Answer (score 3):

This will put the filename in `$1`: `[^:]+://[^/]+/?([^?#]*)`

(p.s. http://rentzsch.github.com/JSRegexTeststand/ is your friend for this sort of test)

Comment: Thank you. This works great however I ended up using a solution by bobince. I though it was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tweaked version of the Reg ex:(added \/ to the existing one)

```
[\w_.-]*?(?=[\/\?\#])|[\w_.-]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function returnPHPname(x) {
    var fileName = x.split(/[#\?]/).shift().split('/').pop()
    return fileName.slice(-3) == 'php'? fileName: ""
}
```

`split(/[#\?]/)`       [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Splitting_with_a_RegExp_to_include_parts_of_the_separator_in_the_result) input on '#' or '?' by a regex [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
`shift()`              [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) out the "leftmost" element from splitted input.
`split('/')`           [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) this element on each slash and return an array.
`pop()`                [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) the "topmost" element of array as an filename.
`slice(-3)`            [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) off three last characters from filename to check..
`'php'? fileName: ""`  'php' returns filename otherwise empty string.

Note that '`\?`' in [regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) is escaped to be a character instead of regex operator.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, rather than just the code itself.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Than you! This got even shorter. Now with explanation too. But I have no explanation why I did left out the explanation :P

Comment: Interesting how functions on array change the array, but functions on string do not change the string but returns a new change of string. So slice will keep filename. But x will change in each step and you actually could store these parts in variables.